# CSS not displaying font very well

Tags: css, webfonts

I have a little problem with my text fonts every time I write a simple font rule and try to display the output, the text is not displayed very well. It usually looks like it is blur. The font is displayed correctly in Mozilla Aurora browser but not displayed well in newer versions of Google Chrome and Firefox. Please, does any one know what could be the cause of this text effect

[image: sample text in Chrome] 
[image: sample text in Aurora]

In these two samples you can observe that the one with the bolder text is Aurora and the one with the faint text is Chrome. These two have the same style rules and have different output. Please, what is the best solution to this.

Comment: Different browsers render fonts differently. There’s no getting around this, I’m afraid. What font are you using?

Comment: font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

Comment: i tried putting this text in a style rule that renders correctly and it gives the correct output, but if i make it a stand alone it renders this way

Comment: “i tried putting this text in a style rule that renders correctly and it gives the correct output, but if i make it a stand alone it renders this way” — you’ve lost me there.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite i mean i tried it in a style rule that gives me the correct output and it works fine. but when i try to display it on its own that is defining its own rule it gives me that output above

Comment: I’m afraid I still don’t understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every rendering engine, Webkit, Mozilla, Trident, etc. was created by a different team of people and therefore will have slight differences in output as well as its own quirks or bugs.

Every browser, Firefox, Safari, Aurora, Chrome, Explorer, etc. was created by a different team of people and therefore will have slight differences in how it utilizes its chosen rendering engine as well as its own quirks or bugs.

The same can be said for each Operating System and how it handles the same fonts.

I'm on a really nice, high resolution LCD display and the difference between the two cases in your image is almost imperceivable. If not for placing them side-by-side, it would be virtually impossible to tell the difference.  I think if you put your test cases on two side by side LCD displays, there would be no perceivable difference.

No matter what you do, all browsers will render things somewhat differently.  Our job as programmers is to reduce these differences only as ***practical*** and possible.